# Работа с регулярными выражениями в django orm

Tags: django-orm, python, sqlite, postgresql, django

Как мы все тут знаем, Django ORM генерирует sql в зависимости от используемой СУБД, и все было хорошо пока мне не понадобилось сделать так:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(column__iregex = "\\bWORD\\b")
```

В SQLite работает, в Postgresql уже нет, там вместо `\b` используют `\y`(или `\m` и `\M`) для определения пределов слова. Незнаю что там там используют в Mysql и Oracle...

Проблему конечно можно решить просто подставляя разную строку в зависимости от используемой СУБД, но это как то не красиво. Может я не правильно работаю с регекспами в django orm?

Comment: «The regular expression syntax is that of the database backend in use.» Django'вский ORM тут не делает никакой абстракции (кроме случая регэкспов для SQLite). Так что вряд ли есть что-то лучше, чем смотреть в `connection.vendor` и подставлять тот или иной синтаксис. Хотя я не уверен, может быть и есть где-то уже готовое решение.

Comment: это печально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего готового не нашел. Как быстрое решение родилось что-то такое:

```
RE_REPLACEMENTS = {
    "postgresql": [
        (r"\{begin-word\}", r"\m"),
        (r"\{begin-word\}", r"\M"),
    ],
    "mysql": [
        (r"\{begin-word\}", "[[:<:]]"),
        (r"\{end-word\}", "[[:>:]]"),
    ],
    "oracle": [
        (r"\{begin-word\}", r"(^|\W)"), # HACK!
        (r"\{end-word\}", r"(\W|$)"), # HACK!
    ]
    "_default_": [
        (r"\{begin-word\}", r"\b"),
        (r"\{end-word\}", r"\b"),
    ]
}

def r(re_regexp):
    from django.db import connection

    rules = RE_REPLACEMENTS.get(connection.vendor, RE_REPLACEMENTS["_default_"])
    for pattern, replacement in rules:
        re_regexp = re.sub(pattern, replacement, re_regexp)

    return re_regexp

...
MyModel.objects.filter(column_iregex=r("{begin-word}WORD{end-word}")
...
```

Код явно не идеален и его стоит еще довести до ума.

Про Oracle — среди [поддерживаемого](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#i1007670) нет аналогов «`\b`», приходится выкручиваться как получится. Lookahead/lookbehind тоже нету, так что аналог только костыльный, увы.

Comment: вроде в postgres тоже есть [[:<:]] [[:>:]]

Comment: Спасибо, не ожидал готовый код. Слегка подправил http://pastebin.com/ASrqnWhG , так как с re заменяет почему-то на пустую строку